# Windows 10 assigned access (kiosk mode) screen scale DPI

Tags: uwp, dpi, kiosk, screen-density

I have an Xamarin UWP application created for assigned access (Kiosk mode).
Now on a new screen the default scaling is set to 150%, my app is looking good on 100%.
Has someone found a way to change the default scaling of the created kiosk user?

Tried to change the DPI settings using registry edition without luck.

Comment: Have you checked my reply about setting the scale in the UWP?

Answer (score 0):

UWP does not have API to set the scale in the app directly. But UWP can get the current scale of the system with [DisplayInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation?view=winrt-22621), so we can modify the size of the control according to the current scale size.

You can refer to the [official sample DpiScaling](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/DpiScaling). The following is a solution based on the sample. The Button control maintains the same size under different scales by controlling the Button's property `FontSize` .

```
    private double oldRawPixelsPerViewPixel;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        DisplayInformation displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
        displayInformation.DpiChanged += DisplayInformation_DpiChanged;

        oldRawPixelsPerViewPixel = 1.0; // your app is looking good on 100%.
        button.FontSize= PxFromPt(20); //default fontsize
    }

    private void ResetOutput()
    {
        DisplayInformation displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
        double rawPixelsPerViewPixel = displayInformation.RawPixelsPerViewPixel;

        double fontSizeInViewPx = button.FontSize / (rawPixelsPerViewPixel / oldRawPixelsPerViewPixel);
        button.FontSize = fontSizeInViewPx;

        oldRawPixelsPerViewPixel = rawPixelsPerViewPixel;
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ResetOutput();
    }
    private void DisplayInformation_DpiChanged(DisplayInformation sender, object args)
    {
        ResetOutput();
    }

    // Helpers to convert between points and pixels.
    double PtFromPx(double pixel)
    {
        return pixel * 72 / 96;
    }

    double PxFromPt(double pt)
    {
        return pt * 96 / 72;
    }
```